# C# / WCF TransactionScopeOption.Required

Tags: c#, transactions

I have 3 question about TransactionScopeOption.Required that driving me crazy and I cant find for them anser online.

**A.** Im having hard time to think When in reality I have to write this code? why shouldnt I just put the DoSomething2() outside TransactionScope4 , in TransactionScope3?
**B.** After this: TransactionScope4.Complete(), TransactionScope3 is Complete too becoude its the same TransactionScope, right?
**C.** In WCF, when I use TransactionScope in client and call some service's methods in it, each method use the TransactionScope that I created in the client or Creat new one? Why should it creat new one? In case the method creat new one, **is that why the attribute: TransactionAutoComplete exsist?**

```
using (TransactionScope TransactionScope3 = new TransactionScope())
            {
                Service1.DoSomething1();
                using (TransactionScope TransactionScope4 = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
                {
                    Service1.DoSomething2();
                    TransactionScope4.Complete();
                }
                TransactionScope3.Complete();
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a key sentence documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.complete.aspx):

> The actual work of commit between the resources manager happens at the End Using statement ***if the TransactionScope object created the transaction***. If it did not create the transaction, the commit occurs whenever Commit is called by the owner of the CommittableTransaction object.

So to answer question **B**, no your call to `TransactionScope4.Complete()` does not commit the transaction, because that TransactionScope instance would have re-used `TransactionScope3`'s transaction.

To answer **C**, if you indicate that a transaction is required for a WCF service, then if there is an existing TransactionScope created on the client, then WCF will not start a new transaction (and it will not commit when the service call ends, for the same reason as stated above). However if the client did not have an open TransactionScope, then WCF would start a new one, and automatically commit or rollback at the end of the service call.

Comment: First of all thank you for the fast comment. Second, From your anser to question C, TransactionAutoComplete need to be used only if I didnt creat TransactionScope in the client. Am I right?

Comment: Btw, I saw I cant make your anser useful, so I will just say that: you anser was Very Useful! Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if calling Complete() on all the nested transaction scopes is necessary or not; you might want to test that, but the `TransactionAutoComplete` setting basically just tells WCF to call `Complete()` for you automatically. I think it is best practice, if not just required, to still call `Complete()` on the transaction scope on the server anyway, even if the client created it. (in other words, I recommend setting it to `true` in your case.)